# Install pip for specific python version

Tags: python, linux, pip, centos, yum

We have installed python 3.9 from external Link, my OS has in built python 3.6 and python3-pip for 3.6 version. If I install pip packages it will install for python 3.6 and it is not compatible for python 3.9. How to install pip3.9 ? so that i will install  packages from pip3.9 command.

OS: Cent OS

I tried like this

```
 python3.9 -m pip
 python3.9: No module named pip
```

Comment: Usually `pip` would be installed along with the rest of the standard library for any recent Python version. Are you able to access other modules from 3.9? Did you disable `pip` installation when you built it? (Or what exactly does "from external link" mean? Somebody else's build?)

Comment: @tripleee, yes. In my case pip is not installed might be my company not added it. If I install from python from python.org it will come along with it. not sure is there any alternate way to deal wit hit

Comment: No, that will only install them for 3.6.

Comment: How about `/path/to/python3.9/python -m pip install abc`. Another suggestion is to use Conda, which handles different python versions pretty effectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some Python distributions may not come with `pip` installed. Try

```
python3.9 -m ensurepip
```

to install `pip` for your interpreter first.

Answer (score -1):

Adding on @Selcuk 's answer, you can define which python version runs pip:

For example:

```
/path/to/python3.9/python -m pip install mypackage
```

This would install `mypackage` for the python version you referenced to.

Another suggestion is to use Conda, which handles different python versions pretty effectively.